# docker-compose command downloading some files, it takes a lot of time

Tags: docker, prisma

i am trying to deploy prisma , but it will throw error that is :
ERROR: No cluster could be found for workspace '*' and cluster 'default'

to solve this problem , i've searched and i got that : 
you have to put managementApiSecret on your docker-compose file,
after putting that I've run docker-compose up -d 
it will downloading some file from while...(my wifi is up-to-date)

so, there is an error in docker-compose.yml file or other issue??
anybody knows anything , please let me know!!
Thank you!!

after running docker-compose up -d:

```
Pulling prisma (prismagraphql/prisma:1.28)...
1.28: Pulling from prismagraphql/prisma
169185f82c45: Already exists
1e929b64ace7: Already exists
950a634ae87e: Pull complete
bc044fe2ebb3: Pull complete
0873a6492f84: Pull complete
4c8d4b619d83: Pull complete
5ae41cd411ee: Pull complete
981b5a112818: Downloading [================================================>  ]  2.762MB/2.835MB
2916748126fc: Download complete
4c1438795551: Download complete
1eacf12374c3: Download complete
c4b88cb35d78: Download complete
601b39379e45: Download complete
736049285c71: Download complete
40c4cc63c060: Download complete
85aef20a5690: Download complete
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.28
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '4466:4466'
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        managementApiSecret: thisismysupersecretkeytext  
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mysql
            host: 192.168.99.1
            port: 3306
            user: root
            password: prisma
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  mysql: ~
```

Comment: What is taking time is downloading the image from dockerhub. I just tested (at work behind a proxy) and I did not get any specific problems (got the image in seconds as expected with the current known bandwidth at this site). If this operation always takes a lot of time from where you are, you need to inspect all network path from your machine to the internet and find out why you don't get the expected bandwidth... or change provider to get more bandwidth.

Comment: Download what? Image? Next time you will not download.